# How to pass data from EJS file to javascript

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I am working in full stack project , I use express to build sever and EJS for rendering pages
the line bellow is for render profile file and pass data to EJS file

```
res.render("profile", { user });
```

my question is how to pass data from this EJS file to 
I tried this way :

```
<% let userPostsData = user.posts %>
 <script>
    let userPostsData = "<%= userPostsData %>";
</script>
```

but I have this error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Comment: use `<%-` for inserting into javascript, and make sure to replace all the `"` characters in the string (assuming `user.posts` is a string -- if it is an object, you are going about this the wrong way)

Comment: can you explain more about if it object ?

Comment: if it's an object, you need to get rid of the quotes around the `<>` and maybe use JSON.stringify: `let userPostsData = <%- JSON.stringify(userPostsData) %>;`

Comment: it has worked , thank you so much